How to get Spring Animations with Constraints to behave properly?
Trying to get a spring animation to work properly.  I made a git repo.  Basically the red view is constrained as follows:
let ac = brokenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: brokenView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 9/16)
let xc = brokenView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: animView.centerXAnchor)
let yc = brokenView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: animView.centerYAnchor)
let widthC = brokenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: animView.widthAnchor)
widthC.priority = .defaultLow
let gewc = brokenView.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: animView.widthAnchor)
let geHC = brokenView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: animView.heightAnchor)
geHC.priority = .required

Blue view starts at aspect ratio != 9/16 -> is animated to 9/16.  What I'd like to see is when the blue view gets too tall, the red view starts to get fat.  Instead it just adheres to the lower priority width anchor.  Any advice is appreciated.
Repo Here
Code that is not as useful as it could be without storyboard file:
import UIKit


class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var animView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var brokenView: UIView!
    
    var isBig = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        brokenView.border(3, color: .red)
        animView.border(3, color: .blue)
        
        animView.frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - 120, y: view.frame.midY - 180, width: 240, height: 360)
        
        brokenView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        let ac = brokenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: brokenView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 9/16)
        let xc = brokenView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: animView.centerXAnchor)
        let yc = brokenView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: animView.centerYAnchor)
        let widthC = brokenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: animView.widthAnchor)
        widthC.priority = .defaultLow
        let gewc = brokenView.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: animView.widthAnchor)
        let geHC = brokenView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: animView.heightAnchor)
        geHC.priority = .required
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            ac,
            xc,
            yc,
            widthC,
            gewc,
            geHC
        ])
        
        let gr = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.handleTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gr)
    }

    
    @objc func handleTap(_ gr: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        let newFrame: CGRect
        if isBig {
            newFrame = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - 120, y: view.frame.midY - 180, width: 240, height: 360)
        } else {
            newFrame = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - (270/2), y: view.frame.midY - (480/2), width: 270, height: 480)
        }
        let timing = UISpringTimingParameters.init(dampingRatio: 0.01, frequencyResponse: 10)
        let anim = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 10, timingParameters: timing)
        anim.addAnimations {
            self.animView.frame = newFrame
        }
        anim.addCompletion { _ in
            self.isBig = !self.isBig
        }
        anim.startAnimation()
    }

}

extension UIView {
    
    func border(_ width: Float, color: UIColor) {
        layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(width)
    }
}

extension UISpringTimingParameters {
    public convenience init(dampingRatio: CGFloat, frequencyResponse: CGFloat) {
        
        let mass = 1 as CGFloat
        let stiffness = pow(2 * .pi / frequencyResponse, 2) * mass
        let damping = 4 * .pi * dampingRatio * mass / frequencyResponse
        
        self.init(mass: mass, stiffness: stiffness, damping: damping, initialVelocity: .zero)
    }
}



??? Why is this voted to close due to lack of clarity??  The problem is clearly stated (constraints are ignored when animating) and there is both a code repo and a picture.

You should have all relevant code in the question itself, rather than linking to a git repo.

@matt that's literally not how it works....

@Paulw11 how does that work with storyboard files?
Does SO just not handle problems that are more complex than a single file?

We can infer some views from a storyboard file.  In this case you could easily create your views and constraints entirely in code. This would be better than a storyboard because we could then easily see what constraints you had in place. A GitHub repo doesn't help unless we are willing to download it and open the project

It's not entirely clear what your end-goal is, but...
UIViewPropertyAnimator with UISpringTimingParameters is a visual effect ... it oscillates with a "spring" until it reaches its "final destination."
This is what it might look like:

it is not continuously changing the frame of the view.
Here's your code, modified so we can explain it:
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let blueAnimView: UIView = UIView()
    let redFollowView: UIView = UIView()
    
    let smallFrameView: UIView = UIView()
    let bigFrameView: UIView = UIView()
    
    var bigRect: CGRect = .zero
    var smallRect: CGRect = .zero
    
    var isBig = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // define the small and big frames (rects)
        smallRect = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - 120, y: view.frame.midY - 180, width: 240, height: 360)
        bigRect = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - (270/2), y: view.frame.midY - (480/2), width: 270, height: 480)
        
        // 3-point red border
        redFollowView.border(3, color: .red)

        // let's make blue view's border thicker to make it easier to see what's going on
        blueAnimView.border(8, color: .blue)

        view.addSubview(bigFrameView)
        view.addSubview(smallFrameView)
        view.addSubview(blueAnimView)
        view.addSubview(redFollowView)
        
        // set the "start" frame of the blue view
        blueAnimView.frame = smallRect

        redFollowView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        // for simplicity, let's constrain redView to blueView on all 4 sides
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            redFollowView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueAnimView.topAnchor),
            redFollowView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueAnimView.leadingAnchor),
            redFollowView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueAnimView.trailingAnchor),
            redFollowView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueAnimView.bottomAnchor),
        ])
        
        let gr = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.handleTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gr)

        // so we can see the small and big frames
        bigFrameView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        smallFrameView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        bigFrameView.frame = bigRect
        smallFrameView.frame = smallRect
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(_ gr: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let newFrame: CGRect
        if isBig {
            newFrame = smallRect
        } else {
            newFrame = bigRect
        }
        
        // slow spring
        let timing = UISpringTimingParameters.init(dampingRatio: 0.01, frequencyResponse: 10)
        
        // quick spring
        //let timing = UISpringTimingParameters.init(dampingRatio: 0.1, frequencyResponse: 0.5)
        
        let anim = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 10, timingParameters: timing)
        anim.addAnimations {
            self.blueAnimView.frame = newFrame
        }
        anim.addCompletion { _ in
            print("completion")
            self.isBig = !self.isBig
        }
        
        anim.startAnimation()
    }
    
}

extension UIView {
    
    func border(_ width: Float, color: UIColor) {
        layer.borderColor = color.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(width)
    }
}

extension UISpringTimingParameters {
    public convenience init(dampingRatio: CGFloat, frequencyResponse: CGFloat) {
        
        let mass = 1 as CGFloat
        let stiffness = pow(2 * .pi / frequencyResponse, 2) * mass
        let damping = 4 * .pi * dampingRatio * mass / frequencyResponse
        
        self.init(mass: mass, stiffness: stiffness, damping: damping, initialVelocity: .zero)
    }
}

First,

let's call the views blueAnimView and  redFollowView
let's declare small and big frames (rects)
let's forget the 9:16 aspect ratio for now, and we'll constrain the redFollowView to all 4 sides of the blueAnimView

Let's also add yellow and systemYellow views so we can see the small and big frames:

When we've add the red and blue views, it looks like this to start:

Now, as soon as we call anim.startAnimation() we see that the redFollowView's constraints cause it to match the "final destination" frame of the blueAnimView:

as the spring animation happens, the redFollowView does not change size, because the blueAnimView's frame is not changing size during the animation:

Here it is slowed-down for clarity:

If you want the red view to follow the blue view as it's animating you'll need to take a different approach.

Edit
To get this desired effect -- Blue view uses Spring animation to change size, and the Red (subview) matches either the width or height while maintaining a 9:16 ratio (effectively a "reverse-aspect-fit"):


We need to toss the idea of constraining the views (see the above discussion).
Instead, we'll:

use explicit frames
implement CADisplayLink
in the display link callback, calculate the new 9:16 frame for the Red view based on the blue view's presentation layer frame

Sample code (no @IBOutlet or @IBAction connections) ... just assign a new, blank view controller to UsingDisplayLinkVC:
class UsingDisplayLinkVC: UIViewController {
    
    let blueAnimView: UIView = UIView()
    let redFollowView: UIView = UIView()
    
    let smallFrameView: UIView = UIView()
    let bigFrameView: UIView = UIView()
    
    var bigRect: CGRect = .zero
    var smallRect: CGRect = .zero
    
    var isBig = false
    
    var displayLink: CADisplayLink!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        // define the small and big frames (rects)
        smallRect = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - 120, y: view.frame.midY - 180, width: 240, height: 360)
        bigRect = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - (270/2), y: view.frame.midY - (480/2), width: 270, height: 480)
        
        // 3-point red border
        redFollowView.border(8, color: .red)
        
        // let's make blue view's border thicker to make it easier to see what's going on
        blueAnimView.border(3, color: .blue)
        
        view.addSubview(bigFrameView)
        view.addSubview(smallFrameView)
        
        // add redFollowView as subview of blueAnimView
        blueAnimView.addSubview(redFollowView)
        
        view.addSubview(blueAnimView)
        
        // set the "start" frame of the blueAnimView
        blueAnimView.frame = smallRect
        
        // calculate and set the redFollowView frame
        let h: CGFloat = blueAnimView.frame.width * 16.0 / 9.0
        redFollowView.frame = .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: blueAnimView.frame.width, height: h)
        redFollowView.center.x = blueAnimView.bounds.midX
        redFollowView.center.y = blueAnimView.bounds.midY
        
        
        let gr = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.handleTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gr)
        
        // so we can see the small and big frames
        bigFrameView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        smallFrameView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        bigFrameView.frame = bigRect
        smallFrameView.frame = smallRect
        
        // init displayLink
        displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(update))

        // start displayLink paused
        displayLink.isPaused = true
        
        // add to run loop
        displayLink.add(to: .current, forMode: .common)

    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(_ gr: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        // if animation is running, return
        if !displayLink.isPaused { return }
        
        let newFrame: CGRect
        if isBig {
            newFrame = smallRect
        } else {
            newFrame = bigRect
        }
        
        // slow spring
        let timing = UISpringTimingParameters.init(dampingRatio: 0.01, frequencyResponse: 10)
        
        // quick spring
        //let timing = UISpringTimingParameters.init(dampingRatio: 0.1, frequencyResponse: 0.5)
        
        let anim = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 10, timingParameters: timing)
        anim.addAnimations {
            self.blueAnimView.frame = newFrame
        }
        
        anim.addCompletion { _ in
            print("completion")
            self.isBig = !self.isBig
            // pause displayLink
            self.displayLink.isPaused = true
        }
        
        // un-pause displayLink
        displayLink.isPaused = false
        
        anim.startAnimation()
        
    }
    
    @objc func update() {

        // get the current frame of blueAnimView's presentation layer
        if let curBlueAnimFrame = blueAnimView.layer.presentation()?.frame {
            let aspect: CGFloat = curBlueAnimFrame.width / curBlueAnimFrame.height
            var w: CGFloat = 0.0
            var h: CGFloat = 0.0
            
            // if curBlueAnimFrame has aspect ratio greater than 9:16
            //  use curBlueAnimFrame width and calculate the new redFollowView height
            // else
            //  use curBlueAnimFrame height and calculate the new redFollowView width
            if aspect > 9.0 / 16.0 {
                w = curBlueAnimFrame.width
                h = w * 16.0 / 9.0
            } else {
                h = curBlueAnimFrame.height
                w = h * 9.0 / 16.0
            }
            // keep redFollowView centered
            let x: CGFloat = curBlueAnimFrame.midX - curBlueAnimFrame.origin.x
            let y: CGFloat = curBlueAnimFrame.midY - curBlueAnimFrame.origin.y
            redFollowView.frame = .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: w, height: h)
            redFollowView.center = .init(x: x, y: y)
        }
        
    }
    
}

Note: this is Sample Code Only!! It is not intended to be, nor should it be considered to be, "production ready."

Edit 2
As discussed in the comments, the above is not quite right. On the update() callback, we:

get the frame of the animated view's presentation layer
calculate the 9:16 frame for the "follow" view
set that view's frame

Unfortunately, when we set the frame it does not visually change until the next draw cycle... when the animated view is already its next size. So the follow view is always one frame behind the animated view.
One option would be to write our own (or find) Spring Animation code then calculate and set both frames on each Display Link update.
Or, we can "cheat" ...

add a clear UIView
animate that view
on each update callback, get that view's presentation layer frame, set the blue view's frame to match, calculate the follow view's frame and set its frame.

Now, both outline views' frames will be set at the same time. We'll still be "one-frame-behind" the animation frame, but since it is clear we won't see it.
Quick sample code to demonstrate:
class CheatVC: UIViewController {
    
    let blueView = UIView()
    let redView = UIView()
    let cheatAnimView = UIView()
    
    let smallFrameView: UIView = UIView()
    let bigFrameView: UIView = UIView()
    
    var bigRect: CGRect = .zero
    var smallRect: CGRect = .zero
    
    var isBig = false
    
    var displayLink: CADisplayLink!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        
        // define the small and big frames (rects)
        smallRect = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - 120, y: view.frame.midY - 180, width: 240, height: 360)
        //smallRect = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - 120, y: view.frame.midY - 80, width: 240, height: 160)
        bigRect = CGRect(x: view.frame.midX - (270/2), y: view.frame.midY - (480/2), width: 270, height: 480)
        
        // 3-point red border
        redView.border(3, color: .red)
        
        // let's make blueView's border thicker to make it easier to see what's going on
        blueView.border(8, color: .blue)
        
        view.addSubview(bigFrameView)
        view.addSubview(smallFrameView)
        
        // add blueView and redView as siblings
        view.addSubview(blueView)
        view.addSubview(redView)
        
        // set the "start" frame of the blueAnimView
        blueView.frame = smallRect
        
        // calculate and set the redView frame
        let h: CGFloat = blueView.frame.width * 16.0 / 9.0
        redView.frame = .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: blueView.frame.width, height: h)
        redView.center = blueView.center
        
        cheatAnimView.frame = smallRect
        view.addSubview(cheatAnimView)
        cheatAnimView.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let gr = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(MyViewController.handleTap(_:)))
        view.addGestureRecognizer(gr)
        
        // so we can see the small and big frames
        bigFrameView.backgroundColor = .systemYellow
        smallFrameView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        bigFrameView.frame = bigRect
        smallFrameView.frame = smallRect
        
        // init displayLink
        displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(update))
        
        // start displayLink paused
        displayLink.isPaused = true
        
        // add to run loop
        displayLink.add(to: .current, forMode: .common)
        
    }
    
    @objc func handleTap(_ gr: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        
        // if animation is running, return
        if !displayLink.isPaused { return }
        
        let newFrame: CGRect
        if isBig {
            newFrame = smallRect
        } else {
            newFrame = bigRect
        }
        
        // slow spring
        var timing = UISpringTimingParameters.init(dampingRatio: 0.01, frequencyResponse: 10)
        
        // quick spring
        timing = UISpringTimingParameters.init(dampingRatio: 0.1, frequencyResponse: 0.15)
        
        let anim = UIViewPropertyAnimator(duration: 2, timingParameters: timing)
        anim.addAnimations {
            self.cheatAnimView.frame = newFrame
        }
        
        anim.addCompletion { _ in
            print("completion")
            self.isBig = !self.isBig
            // pause displayLink
            self.displayLink.isPaused = true
        }
        
        // un-pause displayLink
        displayLink.isPaused = false
        
        anim.startAnimation()
        
    }
    
    @objc func update() {
        // get the current frame of cheatAnimView's presentation layer
        if let curAnimFrame = cheatAnimView.layer.presentation()?.frame {
            let aspect: CGFloat = curAnimFrame.width / curAnimFrame.height
            var w: CGFloat = 0.0
            var h: CGFloat = 0.0
            
            // if blueView's frame has aspect ratio greater than 9:16
            //  use blueView width and calculate the new redView height
            // else
            //  use blueView height and calculate the new redView width
            if aspect > 9.0 / 16.0 {
                w = curAnimFrame.width
                h = w * 16.0 / 9.0
            } else {
                h = curAnimFrame.height
                w = h * 9.0 / 16.0
            }
            
            blueView.frame = curAnimFrame
            
            redView.frame = .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: w, height: h)
            redView.center = blueView.center
        }
        
    }
    
}


Don's explanation is still correct. The animation process doesn't repeatedly apply the constraints.  It simply takes the difference between the starting and ending states and then interpolates the keyframes.  In the case of the spring animation it also extrapolates some keyframes, but that extrapolation is based on the assumption that the parameter would have kept changing in the same was as they did between the start and endpoints.  In your case this isn't what you want to happen.  I don't think that there is an easy way to do this.

@nickneedsaname - yes, the animation will be different if the views are siblings vs parent-child. However, I thought you were looking for an explanation of why the constraints don't follow the animation. It's still not entirely clear what your goal is... Take a look at this: https://i.imgur.com/P1LwtdK.mp4 the "red border view" is a subview of the "blue border view" and the Blue view is being animated. Is that what you're going for?

@DonMag YES HOW DID YOU DO THAT
That is exactly the desired behavior.  "when the blue view gets too tall, the red view starts to get fat."

@nickneedsaname - see the Edit to my answer.


@DonMag so this works preeeettttttttttyyyyyy well.  If you make the spring go fast with lots of springy-ness, it doesn't work so well as we compute our frame based on the current position, which is going to be drastically different from the next position so the following view looks like it's always lagging behind slightly.

@DonMag In practice this isn't an issue (not doing crazy spring anims), but I'm worried about potential for issues in fringe cases (CADisplayLink isn't guaranteed to fire at a consistent rate, depends on system issues, I can see that causing potential glitches that will be hard to track down/diagnose/reproduce)
Do you know if there is a way to synchronize the displaylink to the animation? Or get the next presentation frames? Or to force the redFollowView.frame = .init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: w, height: h) to be rendered immediately?

@nickneedsaname - I think this is as close as you're going to get... using subviews. Depending on your end-goal, you could use a single view and draw the outline frames - but I don't know if that would work with your actual implementation.

@DonMag what does the drawing look like? I can't believe there isn't a way to tell the animation engine "wait let me do something real fast" before every render

Like what I'm leaning towards is somehow trying to reverse engineer the spring animation frames and then use the displaylink timing information to 'guess' (since timing will be almost-but-not-quite-exactly perfect) where the next frame will be and use that (vs presentation) in the display link

@DonMag Here's a crazy thought: Since the initial size of the blue rect is fixed, I could just build a big table of values for blueRect at each step of the animation and use that to compute the redframe in the displaylink.  Essentially the "reverse engineer" without having to do any reverse engineering.

@nickneedsaname - what's your actual goal? Do you only want this outlined-rect animation? Or, are the two views going to have subviews (labels, image views, etc)?

@nickneedsaname - you could take a "cheat" approach.. animate a clear view and set both outline-view frames at each display link update. Still be "one frame behind" ... but the animated view would not be visible, and the two outlines would stay synchronized. Or... I grabbed some manual spring animation code that seems to work pretty well. If you want to continue discussing this, we should probably switch to a chat room.

Okay not going to bother editing since it doesn't work. I have the math as close to perfect as it's going to get.  Errors are biggest first ~2 ticks of the DLink which aren't always as guaranteed; ~0.1 at the highest which is less than a pixel @ 3x resolution so I think that's fine.  The issue is that no matter what I do it does not line up properly, I'm seeing visual errors on the order of 10+ pixels which just doesn't make any sense.  'Animate clear frame' works perfectly fine so I'm just going to do that.  Thanks again!!!

@nickneedsaname - yeah, animating a clear view and updating both red and blue frames seems like a reasonable option. I gave my answer an Edit 2 describing the issue, along with sample code for the "cheat" option.

@DonMag if you want to poke around @ the math: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/sxlgip2prq -- g(x) is the 'naive' spring animation that you'll get all over the internet.  f(x) is the one where phi is computed so we have 0 velocity @ t=0 and B is computed so that f(x) = A_init @ t=0.  Pretty happy with how well f(x) fits the x_actual

The one thing I could not figure out is how duration is calculated.... That's what all the 1st/2nd/3rd derivatives are there for.  Without thinking too hard the anim is over when it's done changing a lot, so maybe when a derivative (1st or 2nd?) is below a thresh? or something?

@DonMag Also fwiw I think you're right the proper way to do it would be to run our own custom animation on top of a CADisplayLink so we can manually do stuff, but I don't want to deal with that right now.  Cheat works well enough.
